# Turning on Bitlocker on non system drive without tpm without password

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I need to turn on Bitlocker on all drives:

1) On C: I am able to turn on Bitlcoker with password and that is fine

2)On non system drive when I am turning on bitlocker it is asking me to provide password for each individual drive even after turning on autounlock

3)I want non system drives to automatically unlock once system drive is unlocked.

[image]

I used

```
manage-bde f: -autounlock -enable
```

to enable auto unlock

Comment: So is the problem that you cannot configure auto unlock? What have you tried? What error messages do you get?

Comment: I have configured all the drives, and turned on auto unlock, but whenever I am restarting the machine it is in the locked state and I have to unlock manually...

Comment: Did you configure them for auto unlock? Tell us what command you used. Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: What output did the command give? Also, it has autounlock misspelled, though I assume that's just a typo.

Comment: Is your system drive encrypted with BitLocker?